# Proximity Prompt can be clicked but does nothing in roblox studio

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a proximity prompt that when I hold "e" it should display a shopkeeper and print your level and money in the chat but it doesn't do anything like that. When I press and hold "E" it does nothing.
here is my code for the proximity part:

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

local shopMan = game.ReplicatedStorage.shopMan
local clonedShopMan = shopMan:Clone()
local username = Players.Name
local money = _G.publicPlayerSession.Money
local level = _G.publicPlayerSession.Level
local purchased = false

function loadData()
    
    if level == 1 then
        --new stand for free
    elseif level == 2 then
        --stand with another worker
    end
end

script.Parent.Triggered:Connect(function(player)
    print(money)
    print(level)
    if level > 0 then
        purchased = true
        loadData()
    else
        purchased = false
    end
    
    if purchased == false then
        if money >= 150 then
            money -= 150
            level += 1
            clonedShopMan.Parent = workspace.Stand
            script.Parent:Destroy()
        end
    end
end)
```

I tried change some of the code like removing player from the function and trying to change variable names but nothing was working I had the same result

Answer (score 1):

The variables will not update dynamically when the table's content change.

Comment: im new to lua so how could i fix that

Comment: just do:
script.Parent.Triggered:Connect(function(player)
 money = _G.publicPlayerSession.Money
 level = _G.publicPlayerSession.Level
 print(money)
    print(level)